# Bootstrap 4: Can't align items inside columns

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

i have read previous questions and answers and tried to apply available solutions with no result.

1. How to align items inside columns?
2. how to make image size fit column width?

```
<section>
  <div class="container-fluid idx-sec1">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-5">
        <img style="width:125%" src="{%static 'images/idx-sec1-m.png' %}" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="col-7">
        <h1> FIBLIT is leading </h1>
        <span>The future of Technology</span>
        <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
           Fuga placeat ratione consequatur aperiam laborum omnis ab 
           accusantium laboriosam quam debitis.
        </p>
        <button class="btn">Discover</button>      
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

```
.idx-sec1{
    background-image: url(../images/idx-sec1-f.jpg);
    height: 100vh;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Please be more specific about what you mean by aligning items within the columns. To make the image fit inside the column width, you can give it a `width: 100%`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How to align items inside columns?**

You can add bootstrap classes to your `row` or `col` depending on your need.

to align all children `col`

```
<div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">...</div>
```

or to align elements inside a specific `col`

```
 <div class="col-7 align-self-center">...</div>
 //or
 <div class="col-7 text-center">...</div>
```

**How to make image size fit column width?**

Use the `img-fluid` class in your ``img` tag. E.g.

```
<img src="" class="img-fluid" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and support... it work well with me.